# What's the syntactic function of 'playing together' in: " They spent the day playing together"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

My attempt to analyse this sentence:

```
sbj: They
vrb: spent
        obj: the day
```

What is the function of the participle phrase "playing together"?

Comment: I'm assuming that the user who close-voted this doesn't know what a syntactic function / grammatical relations are. If you don't, please stop "close/keep open"voting on grammar questions.

Comment: I the user doesn't know those things, they should be in ELL...

Comment: *Playing* is a present participle modifying the subject *they*, and *together* is an adverb modifying the present participle *playing*.

Answer (score 6):

It's a complement of *spent*.

*Spend (time)* usually requires a complement as well as its object, which can take several forms:

- Prepositional phrase: *in the city*.
- Adjectival phrase: *bored*.
- Participial phrase: *playing together*.
- Adverb: *together*.

Comment: So its an objective complement of "the day"?

Comment: I don't think so. It is the verb _spend_ (like _waste_) that requires an object and a complement, not the NP _the day_.

Comment: I thought only linking verbs could have complements. If "playing together" is a complement, it can only be an objective complement.

Comment: @William It is a complement of the verb, but it is a subject complement because it "describes" the subject (actually it takes the subject as its own subject), not the object.

Comment: @William You could analyse 'spend the day' / 'spend time' / 'occupy themselves' / as (or as behaving like) MW link verbs: [They] [spent two hours / were / continued] [playing together].

Comment: Yes, and comparing "spend" with "put", in parallel with the PP complement of "put" which tells where you put something, "spend" perhaps takes a PP complement, typically with "at", which answers the question "How did you spend that time?"  The "at" can be understood.

Comment: @William I've tried to explain a bit more about Complements in my post below.

Answer (score 2):

**A bit about Complements:**

Verbs set up different special slots for different kinds of phrases. All verbs set up a space for a Subject. How many other slots the verb sets up, if any, and what types of job these phrases are doing depends on the verb. In addition to a slot for a putter, he verb *PUT* also sets up a slot for the thing being moved and another slot for the destination of that thing.

The phrases that fill these different slots set up by other words or phrases are called *Complements*. Apart from a Subject, the verb *PUT* takes two Complements. The thing being moved is the *Direct Object*, the phrase indicating the destination is the *Locative  Complement*.

**The Original Poster's example:**

> We spent the day playing together.

In the sentence above the verb *SPEND* is taking a Direct Object and a Catenative Complement. The Direct Object is the phrase *the day*. The phrase *playing together* is the Catenative Complement. It is also a non-finite clause. This sentence is unusual because our interpretation of the Subject of the verb *playing* is controlled by the Subject of the main clause. We understand the sentence like this:

- We<sub>(1)</sub> spent the day [ ___<sub>(1)</sub> playing together].

We could also construe it like this:

- **We** spent the day [**us** playing together].

Why is this unusual? Well when a verb takes both a Direct Object and a Catenative Complement, our interpretation of the Subject of the non-finite clause is usually controlled by the *Object* of the main clause, not the Subject. Consider this example:

- I persuaded Bob to eat the pasta.

We understand this sentence like this:

- I persuaded Bob<sub>(1)</sub> [ ___<sub>(1)</sub> to eat the pasta].
- I persuaded **Bob** [ **Bob** to eat the pasta].

The sentence doesn't mean:

- I<sub>(1)</sub> persuaded Bob [ ___<sub>(1)</sub> to eat the pasta]. (wrong)
- **I** persuaded Bob [**me** to eat the pasta]. (wrong)

The verb *SPEND*, therefore is unusual because it has a Direct Object, but it relies on Subject and not Object control. Because of the Subject control involved in the Original Poster's sentence, we probably want to think of the Catenative Complement as being a subject-oriented Complement.

Comment: Begin with "They spent the day playing together, and we spent the day playing together, too", and note what happens when you pronominalize: "They spent the day playing together, and we spent the day at it, too.".  The fact that "playing together" is replaced by "it" with the antecedent "playing together" is evidence that it is a NP (a nominalized sentence), and the "at" that crops up is evidence that we are dealing with a PP complement.  (I dislike your term "catenative" -- it doesn't mean anything.)

Comment: @GregLee Not my term! It's from Pullum or Hussdleston. I defer to their greater knowledge. Why *at it*, btw? I find the evidence rather weak, although I'm not saying it's wrong. Why not *doing it*?

Comment: @GregLee Your example doesn't seem to work with *They spent the day being sad, and we spent the day at it too*. It's interesting though ...

Comment: Maybe it's not a PP -- maybe it's a manner adverb (if that counts as a genuine part of speech). Note "We spent the day *that way* too."  It's arguable.  But at least it's meaningful.  Calling it a "catenative complement" seems like empty terminology, to me, regardless of who said it first.

Comment: @GregLee but "manner adverb" as you say is a part of speech, not a term for a grammatical relation!

Comment: In conventional generative grammar, we don't build syntax trees with grammatical relations (that would be Relational Grammar).  We use parts of speech.  (Chomsky argued this in **Aspects**.  Amusingly, though, he did use Manner in some of his trees, discussing the passive.)

Comment: @GregLee It's the grammatical relations that the OP's asking about though ... So maybe you should let me off the hook! :)

Comment: The grammatical relation is that it's a complement of the verb, as Colin Fine said in his answer.  "Catenative"??  What does it say?  Now, if I say it's a manner adverb, that tells us it can be questioned with "how".

Comment: @GregLee Yes, but "complement" is very vague. Direct Object, Indirect Object, Locative Complement, Predicative Complement, Extraposed Subject, Extraposed Object, Catenative Complement and arguably even "Subject" are all types of complement, so complement doesn't really tell us anything much. Saying that it's a manner adverb might be informative, but not about the function, only about the part of speech.

Answer (score 0):

"playing together" is a how-indication and I would simply call it adverbial sentence part. I think here a prepostion such as "by/with" or something similar was dropped.

Comment: You can't say "I spent the day". It isn't complete without some adjective. Therefore the phrase is some kind of complement and not a modifier.